# Não consigo diminuir imagem no css

Tags: html, css, image

Estou tentando criar uma tela de login, na hora de diminuir a imagem ele permanece igual. Tentei por, na classe da imagem, width de 50% mas nada mudou, segue o codigo:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main class="principal">
            <section class="principal__um">
                <img class="imagem" src="./assets/phone.png" alt="Foto de Pessoa usando o celular">
                <h1>Comece de graça e consiga enormes vantagens.</h1>
            </section>
            <section class="principal__dois">
                <h2>Faça seu cadastro</h2>
                <div class="login">
                    <p>Já tem uma conta? </p>
                    <p>Login</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="#">Faça login com Google</a>
                <a href="#">Faça login com Facebook</a>
                </div>
                <p> ou </p>
                <form action="#">
                    <label for="email"></label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="">
                </form>
                <form action="">
                    <label for="password"></label>
                    <input type="hidden" name="password">
                </form>
            </section>
    </main>
    
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.principal{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: solid;
    height: 100vh;


}

.principal__um{
    border: solid;
}


    .imagem{
        height: 50%;
    }
    
    
    .login{
        display: flex;
    }
```

Comment: é que na classe pai `principal__um` não especificou a altura, e a classe `imagem` ta seguindo essa especificação. Se colocar o `height` na classe `principal__um` deve resolver o tamanho, `.principal__um{border: solid; height: 100%;}`

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2):

Olá, segue uma sugestão de forma de regular o tamanho da imagem.

1º Crie uma "div" com as especificações desejadas de tamanho.

2º Atribua uma classe tipo "div-img".

3º No CSS, atribua as seguintes propriedades:

```css
.div-image {
  background-image: url(' Insira o caminho para imagem... ');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Consiste em transformar uma div em imagem, dessa forma você pode usar as propriedades de manipulação de div á uma imagem.

Essa é uma das muitas formas possíveis, espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Bom dia! Para diminuir a imagem, você deve colocar ela em uma div, e definir alutura e largura da div contendo a imagem.  Aconselho apenas definir a largura, pois a altura já se adapta de acordo com a largura.

Answer (score -3):

Vamos supor que vc queira que a imagem tenha 50% de largura e altura
tente fazer assim:

```
 .imagem{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    object-fit: contain;
  }
```

ou se desejar que a imagem ocupe o seu container todo sem prejudicar a qualidade

```
  .imagem{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
```

Esse [doc tem mais detalhes sobre o uso do object-fit](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp) em imagens

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).